# Swift Storyboards MAC OSX 10.9 deployment

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, deployment

I made a Swift Storyboards project, fully working on MAC OS X 10.10, when I try on MAC OS X 10.9 the program's windows do not appear. I'm wondering if the Storyboards feature is only available for MAC OS X 10.10. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, storyboards are new in OSX 10.10, as you can easily find out in the [OSX API diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/APIDiffsMacOSX10_10SeedDiff/frameworks/AppKit.html).
Or in the [AppKit Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#10_10Storyboards). etc

Comment: So basically I can't use my app within OS X 10.9?

Comment: Right, you can't. You would have to rewrite it w/o storyboards (just xibs/nibs). Note: You can tell Xcode what your minimum deployment target is and what SDK version you want to use. Click on the project and the target. 'General' tab.

Comment: I can select 10.9 target also with storyboards, it's a very nasty bug I think

Comment: No, it's not a nasty bug, though a warning might be nice. You can develop an app which runs on 10.9 but has storyboards for 10.10 specific stuff. It's a reasonable assumption that the developer knows what features his target platform provides (and Apple provides extensive change documentation).

Comment: No warning is a bug if you ask me.

Comment: ? If you think so: radar.apple.com